# Get text of element within same parent

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML. What I try to achieve is to get the back text of the `h4` in the change function what is called by `#my_id` selectbox.

```
<div class="product_box">
    <h4>title</h4>
    <select id="my_id">
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="2"></option>
        <option value="4"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```javascript
$("#ajax_call").change(function(){
    var count = $('#ajax_call :selected').val();
    var prod_modul =$('#ajax_call').parents();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean `..back text of h4..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the parent element as a context, like this:

```
$("#my_id").change(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest(".product_box");
    var text = $("h4", $parent).text();
});
```

Or if you can guarantee that the `h4` will **always** be the previous element to the `select`, then you can use `prev()`:

```
$("#my_id").change(function() {
    var text = $(this).prev().text();
});
```

My preference is the former as it does not rely on the position of the elements remaining the same - which can never really be guaranteed. Always use `next()` and `prev()` with caution.

Comment: Thanks actually the first block of code is what I want. The problem is that the product_box div is generated with php and is more time present in my html structure. the change function doesn't seems to fire just on the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Use [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$("#my_id").change(function() {
    var text = $(this).siblings("h4").text();
    //.....
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eBPvv/)